# Pathing using ./, ../, .. - what do they exactly mean for my view files?

Tags: php, html

I always worry about pathing issues when I move my website into subfolders because I don't know how to handle it with PHP.

I want to learn this with an example because I can easily learn it by looking at examples.

Let's say I have a website running at this directory: `httpdocs/development/subfolder/myWebsite/index.php`

By default, PHP would run `httpdocs/index.php`, so it is the root path but my website runs in a subfolder.

In my website's index.php, (so we're in a subfolder) how can I ensure I point correct folders?

```
<img src="images/1.jpg"> // Does no dot means root path?

<img src="./images/1.jpg"> //Does ./ means which_directory_our_php_page_currently_in/images?

<a href="./"> // Points /subfolder/myWebsite/ or httpdocs/ ?

<a href=".."> //Same as above, but no front slash.

<a href=""> //Same as above
```

I don't want to make a definition or a const to track it with PHP and change it whenever I move my files. Like:

```
define('SITE_PATH', './development/subfolder/myWebsite/');
```

Especially when it comes into `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, things only get more confusing.

I would like to know how to handle it with PHP professionally; what is the difference between  and `./`; lastly what does `..` mean without forward slash.

Thank you.

Comment: Defining a constant for the base path is a good way to handle it because if you change your root path you just change the constant and that's it.

Comment: It could be done without necessity to change it. Like, define('SITE_PATH', __ DIR __); in index.php. Not sure if it would work, but a solution like this would be more beneficial for me cause I don't need to change that line each time I move my website into different subfolders.

Comment: Most php frameworks have code to determine the base path in different environments since one method alone may not work moving between different servers. I would suggest look at a few frameworks and see how they determine the base path.

Comment: For `href`'s, look at the urls, not at your local paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the paths in your examples are relative, meaning they are based off of the current location.  Starting a path with a `/` means it's an absolute path, based on the root of the site.

If you want to always be 100% sure of what you're referencing use the `/` at the front of your paths.

Comment: so images/ in reality is equal to ./images/? And what is .., is it equal to ../?

Comment: `images/` is relative to the path that the current page is in. `./' and `.` refer to the same directory and `images/` refers to the `images` directory contained in the directory that holds the current page.

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX systems, `'./dirName'` looks for a sub-directory `dirName` in the current directory; `.` simply refers to the current location. In other words, `./dirName` is equivalent to `'dirName'`. You don't use that in an href though: for paths relative to the current location, do not use the preceding `.`.

`'../dirName'` looks for a sub-directory `dirName` in the parent of the current directory. `..` refers to the parent directory.

If the filepath begins with a forward slash, it is referring to the root directory. `'/dirName'` refers to a sub-directory `dirName` located inside the root directory.

Comment: Helpful reply. Thanks alot. :)